# Changing phone number with contact name

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have a table for contacts like

```
Contacts
number (Primary key)
name   (name of the contact)

Messages
id (primary key)
number (reciever or sender's phone number)
type (sent or recieved)
text (message body)
date (timestamp)
```

What I want is, when I query the messages, and group them by phone number to make a conversation, i would like to change the phone number in the Messages table to change with the name of the contact in contacts table if present, if not present leave the phone number as a phone number as there are unknown numbers who can text too. PS I have googled a lot to find a solution but didn't find one.

For example,

```
Contacts table contain
 id     name
 1       a
 2       b

Messages Contain
 id   number  type      text   date
 1      1       sent    haha   123456
 2      3      recieved  hi    123459
```

Now result should be

```
   number    type       text      date
     a       sent       haha     123456
     3       received   hi       123459
```

Comment: Sample input and expected output would pinpoint your requirement

Comment: @1000111 sorry, didn;t get your point

Comment: I asked for some sample input and expected output based on that sample input. Also share your current query

Comment: There can be multiple messages of a particular contact. Since your expected result contains one row for each contact so which message do you want to display in your result set? latest one?

Comment: @1000111 I want to show all the messages, I just want to change phone number with its corresponding name if it exists in a contacts table, if name does not exists in contacts table leave the number as it is

Comment: Any suggestion ? if the solution needs to change table structure i would totally do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `LEFT JOIN` between `Messages` table and `Contacts` table.

```
SELECT 
 COALESCE(c.name,m.id) AS number,
 m.type,
 m.text,
 m.date
FROM messages m 
LEFT JOIN contacts C  ON m.number = C.id;
```

---

**Note:**

MySQL <kbd>[**COALESCE()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)</kbd> function returns the first non-NULL value of a list, or NULL if there are no non-NULL values.

```
mysql> SELECT COALESCE(NULL, 2, 3);
+----------------------+
| COALESCE(NULL, 2, 3) |
+----------------------+
|                    2 |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
mysql> SELECT COALESCE(NULL, NULL, NULL);
+----------------------------+
| COALESCE(NULL, NULL, NULL) |
+----------------------------+
|                       NULL |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This is just awesome, ......